# Pre Populate Django Users From LDAP

Tags: python, django, ldap

I'm using Django Auth LDAP for authentication for my django app.  However, the user object is not created until the user attempts to log in.

So I'm trying to pre populate all the users from ldap, but currently it is not populating any fields other than name and username.  Not email, not is_superuser, etc.

Code to get list of usernames then attempt to populate users:

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend

l = ldap.initialize(LDAP_SERVER_URI)
l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
l.simple_bind(LDAP_BIND_DN, LDAP_BIND_PASS)

search_filter = LDAP_USER_SEARCH_FILTER
attributes = ['*']

backend = LDAPBackend()
results = l.search_s(LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, search_filter, attributes)
return Response(results)
for query, u in results:
    username = u[LDAP_ATTR_USERNAME][0].decode('utf-8')
    user, created = backend.get_or_build_user(username, u)
    if created:
        user.save()
    backend.populate_user(username)
    log.debug(f'Pre-populate: {user}, {user.email}')
```

How can I create all the users and have their info set correctly as if they logged in with django-auth-ldap, without them having to login?

---

#### Edit: Added map variables

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    'first_name': LDAP_ATTR_FIRST_NAME,
    'last_name': LDAP_ATTR_LAST_NAME,
    'email': LDAP_ATTR_EMAIL,
}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_staff": LDAP_STAFF_GROUP,
    "is_superuser": LDAP_SUPERUSER_GROUP,
}
```

Comment: Have you configured AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP or AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP?

Comment: @TimNyborg Yes.  I added them to my question for reference.

Answer (score 0):

`backend.populate_user(username)` updates and returns the User instance, but doesn't save it, so you need to get that User and save it:

```py
for query, u in results:
    username = u[LDAP_ATTR_USERNAME][0].decode('utf-8')
    user, created = backend.get_or_build_user(username, u)
    if created:
        user.save()
    user = backend.populate_user(username)
    user.save()
    log.debug(f'Pre-populate: {user}, {user.email}')
```

Comment: I've been triying this but `populate_user()` is returning `None` when I've been trying this.

Comment: Then it sounds like it's encountering an ldap error, and you should enable logging for the module to figure out what.